# When processing a csv String with an empty final field, myString.split( "," ) returns incorrect number of array entries

Tags: java, android, string, split

I'm processing a certain line read from a .csv file using `String.split(",")` and finding that the final empty string after the last delimiter is not making it into the array created by the `split` function.

Here are the variable values that are causing the error:

```
String toSplit = "1,Some Value,31337,Another Value,";
String[] values = toSplit.split( "," );
```

The `values` array ends up having fewer than the expected count of array entries.  The array created is:

```
values[0] : '1'
values[1] : 'Some Value'
values[2] : '31337'
values[3] : 'Another Value'
```

with a `values[4]` throwing an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception.

The array I want is:

```
values[0] : '1'
values[1] : 'Some Value'
values[2] : '31337'
values[3] : 'Another Value'
values[4] : ''
```

One caveat: I am reading the output of another .csv file creator and don't want to use string delimiters or throw a ' ' whitespace character into places where the data is empty.  (ie. do not want: `toSplit = "1,Some Value,31337,Another Value, "` with whitespace on the end.)

Is this a bug in String.split() and is there a workaround/another option?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Figured it out as I was entering the question!  Use **stringObj.split( ",", numDelimitersExpected )** or, as @Supericy pointed out, **stringObj.split( ",", -1 )**.

According to the Android docs about [stringObj.split( delimiter )](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#split%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) a call to `line.split( "," )` is equivalent to a call to `line.split( ",", 0 )` with the second argument referring to `limit`, which sets the '*maximum number of entries*' and defines the '*treatment of trailing empty strings*' .  Looking at the documentation for [stringObj.split( delimiter )](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#split%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) it states that with `limit == 0` '**trailing empty strings will not be returned**'.

The solution is to use a call to `split( ",", limit )` with `limit` set to the **number of array entries you expect to get back**.  In my case a limit set to 5 returns the array

```
values[0] : '1'
values[1] : 'Some Value'
values[2] : '31337'
values[3] : 'Another Value'
values[4] : ''
```

which is exactly what I wanted.  **Problem solved.**

In fact, even if your `toSplit` string has less delimiters than `limit`, a call with a set `limit` will still create empty array entries up to `limit`.  For example, with the same input string as in my question:

```
String toSplit = "1,Some Value,31337,Another Value,"
```

a call `String values[] = toSplit.split( ",", 8 )` returns the array

```
values[0] : '1'
values[1] : 'Some Value'
values[2] : '31337'
values[3] : 'Another Value'
values[4] : ''
values[5] : ''
values[6] : ''
values[7] : ''
```

**Neat!**

Note: Oracle's Java [String.split( delimiter )](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) has the same functionality with the Android docs winning for their more concise explanation.  (:

Edit: As @Supericy added, `toSplit.split( ",", -1 )` would also **properly return the trailing empty entry**.  Thanks for the addition!

Comment: Within one minute the question and the answer are present! :D

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `String.split(delimiter, -1)` if you don't know the number of entries ahead of time. Also, the javadoc *does* tell you that it is calling `String.split(del, limit)` with a limit of zero; so your reason behind android docs being better is moot.

Comment: @Supericy: Good call with -1 limit!  And yes, I did read that the Oracle docs explain that functionality as well, but the Android docs make use of functional encapsulation that says exactly the same thing as the Oracle docs but more concisely.  Note: I didn't state the documentation was wrong, just that it was less concise.  They are both complete.  One is both complete and also shorter, hence it wins.  (:  Thanks for your input!

Comment: Nice job. I was struggling with this in my implementation of 'explode' in PL/SQL. Now I have limit as well :D