# Splitting strings by "," using Java

Tags: java, swing

I have a notepad file like this

> 550-001,w,009.95,Pears Turkey,abc
>   550-002,P,012.95,Pears Syrian,def
>   550-003,w,009.95,Pears Lebanese,ghi
>   550-005,w,009.95,Pears Golden,jkl
>   550-006,w,007.95,Aus Carrot,

I am splitting this text by "," means whenever "," comes it split like this

> 550-001
>   w
>   009.95
>   abc
>   etc.........
>   atlast
>   550-006
>   w
>   007.95
>   Aus Carrot

For this line after "," there is no string, so it sends error for this line and skip this line.

How do I recognize that there is no string character?

Comment: I've added the java tag for you so the question attracts more attention. But you ought to improve the question quality though.

Comment: Please add code snippet that you have tried.

Comment: show us your attempt?

Comment: Show the java-code that produced this error.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in split method

```
String[] array = yourString.split(",")
```

Here array is an array of String that contains all the elements contained in the String yourString.

In order to check if there's a string after one coma just check that the element at a given index has a non-zero length.

```
String line="";
boolean error=false;
for(String elem : array){
    if(element.length()>0)
        line+=elem+"\n";
    else {
        System.err.println(error here, we skip the line)
        error=true;
    }
}
if(!error)
    System.out.println(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using String.split(",") ?

If so, it returns an array of the strings. Check this array has the correct number of entries, and that each entry has a length > 0.

This question [When processing a csv String with an empty final field, myString.split( "," ) returns incorrect number of array entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755003/when-processing-a-csv-string-with-an-empty-final-field-mystring-split-re) looks similar, and should help you out further.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if (str==null || str.equals("")){//you only need one of these checks
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> For this line after "," there is no string, so it sends error for this line and skip this line. How do I recognize that there is no string character?

So your issue is that you're getting an empty string, because your code ends in a `,`.

**Solution**

```
String test = "This,is,a,test,";

String[] tokens = test.split(",");

for(String s : tokens)
{
    if(s != null && !s.equals("")) {
       // Do your code.
    }
}
```

And [here](http://ideone.com/SKV8bi) is an ideone.com link to the working code.